# Send Specific Values to BinaryWriter

Tags: vb.net, binarywriter

i need help  here, i did run out of ideas.
I need to do in the following code, to be able to chose a file from within the project (My.resources), instead of HardCoding  this line 
`FSR.Write(My.Resources._1_5, 0, My.Resources._1_5.Length)`
 i would like to be able to pass a selected value, but i cant store `My.Resources._1_5` into a Byte variable, it kept on saying cannot store 1 dimensional array of Bytes into Byte. _1_5 is a doc file, and i have a long list of files i want to be able to chose from.

```
 Dim TempFileName As String = "TMPDoc.doc"
        Dim TempFolder As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Temp
        Dim path As String = Application.StartupPath & "\"
        TempFileName = path & TempFileName

        Dim FS As New System.IO.FileStream(TempFileName, IO.FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
        Dim FSR As New System.IO.BinaryWriter(FS)
        FSR.Write(My.Resources._1_5, 0, My.Resources._1_5.Length)
        FSR.Close()
        FS.Close()

        appWord.Documents.Open(TempFileName)
```

Not sure if i am explaining myself.

Comment: It is a Byte() variable, not a Byte variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as is most likely the case, the `My.Resources._1_5` property is exposed as a byte array, then you can simply create a byte array variable to point to it, like this:

```
Dim resource_1_5() As Byte = My.Resources._1_5
```

Or you could create a list of byte arrays and add it to the list, like this:

```
Dim resources As New List(Of Byte())()
resources.Add(My.Resources._1_5)
```

However, what you may really be trying to do is just access the resource by string name rather than via a concrete property.  If that's the case, you can get it by name via the `ResourceManager`, like this:

```
Dim resource_1_5() As Byte = DirectCast(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("_1_5", My.Resources.Culture), Byte())
```

Note that in the above sample, the `GetObject` method returns a `Byte` array, but it casts it as `Object`.  Therefore, you need to use `DirectCast` or `CType` to cast it back to a `Byte` array.

Comment: Worked as intended :D Thanks a lot for the help! sorry for the late reply